# Passing data between ViewControllers using NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, segue, nsuserdefaults

I have textfields on one page and labels on the other and I am trying to pass the data typed in the textfield.

When I press my segue button I would like the data to display on the labels on my second viewcontroller.

I already have a `prepareForSegue` function to pass the data but it isn't permanent and is gone the moment I change pages.

I guess my question is do I still need the `prepareForSegue` function if I am using permanent storage? Or should I get rid of it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  It sounds like you no longer need to do what prepareForSegue does because you're storing and loading your data elsewhere - in which case, no, you don't need to keep around a function that no longer does anything useful - but without knowing what else prepareForSegue might be doing in your application, it's impossible to say for sure whether it's safe to get rid of it.

Comment: Do you want to show that text in second page only or else where also?

Comment: The actual question you should ask yourself is if it is really a "user default" or just a string that needs to be passed. Imho it makes no sense to store "myLabelText" in NSUserDefaults if you just need it passed and then forget it.

Comment: My prepareForSegue function passed my data from my textfields in one viewcontroller into my label in another viewcontroller and displayed the data that's it. However, the data doesnt save, if I change to another page the data is gone. I need the data from the textfields to be stored and displayed in the labels until I want to change them again via the same process as the first time. So it sounds like I no longer need to have a prepareForSegue function anymore based on these comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prepareForSegue allows you to pass information between two controllers. If your second "labels" controller doesn't need to know anything about the state the previous "textfields" controller was in, then you don't have to pass anything.

That being said, fetching data in a "permanent storage" has a cost: it takes time/cpu.
So, if both controllers display the same data, it might be more interesting to fetch it once when you load the "textfields" controller (assuming it always have to be loaded), and pass it to "labels".

Comment: Thank you for the answer I figured out what I was doing wrong.